# Set BatchSize for specific function of a WebJob

Tags: azure-webjobs

Is is possible to set batch size on function level within a webjob?

I have multiple functions in a webjob, some of them depend on other external APIs which does not allow a high degree of parallelization.

I have seen only the Singleton attribute which is not exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

just figured out that this is possible with a custom QueueProcessorFactory I already use.

An example from MS is here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/MiscOperations/CustomQueueProcessorFactory.cs

Having attributes for this would be nice ;-)

Alex

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, custom QueueProcessor instances are designed were designed to be the "escape hatch" allowing you full control in advanced scenarios. We want to keep the mainline paths simple and easy to use, while allowing you to drop down and deeply customize when needed. Adding a bunch of override options on QueueTriggerAttribute itself would be possible, but could also complicate the programming model.

If you would like to suggest a change, I suggest you log issues in the public repo: https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues

Thanks :)